# subtype hierarchy

Tags: java

So lets say I were to draw the class hierarchy of `List<?>`.  Would `List<Object>` be a subtype of `List<?>`

Then would `List<Integer>` be a subtype of `List<Object>` or would it be a subtype of `List<?>`?

Thanks

Comment: What? List cannot be subtype of itself.

Comment: Once you get 2000+ in rep, you've earned the advantage of being able to see the source of the post ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then would `List<Integer>` be a subtype of `List<Object>`?

No, generic classes in Java are [not covariant](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01255.html).

From the above link:

> It turns out there's a good reason it doesn't work that way: It would break the type safety generics were supposed to provide. Imagine you could assign a `List<Integer>` to a `List<Number>`. Then the following code would allow you to put something that wasn't an `Integer` into a `List<Integer>`:
>
> ```
> List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
> List<Number> ln = li; // illegal
> ln.add(new Float(3.1415));
> ```

---

`List<?>` is slightly different and if I understand it correctly, it is similar to the raw type in the sense that the type parameter here is *unknown*. Here for instance, the second line compiles fine, but now the third line is illegal, since the compiler can say for sure that it is a legal `add` operation:

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<?> ln = li;
ln.add(new Float(3.1415)); // illegal
```

Thus by assuming the "is assignable to" definition of subtype, I suppose `List<Object>` is a subtype of `List<?>`.

Comment: So with the exception of List<?>, are you saying generic classes cannot have subtypes, like List<Number> cannot have a subtype?

Comment: Oh, sure it can. Here is a subtype of `List<Number>`:  `class SomeClass extends List<Number> {}`.

Answer (score 0):

The only place where a class or interface is it's own child is in the evaluation of generic bounds.

Some example method signatures:

```
public <E extends<Enum<E>> void doSomeThingWithAnEnum(E item);

public <S extends Comparable<? super S>> void sort(S[] items);
```

But this is not a real type hierarchy, all of this info is removed by the compiler. The resulting byte code is roughly equivalent to:

```
public void doSomeThingWithAnEnum(Enum item);

public void sort(Comparable[] items);
```